Flutter Web Integration with Stripe Check-out links
I am planning to add Stripe payment check out links into my Flutter web app but I have some dilemmas and questions.

I am using Stripe link as I want to checkout to happen at Stripe site (links)

I want users to pay before they register in my app (Firebase Auth) or even better if they are automatically registered too at my app once they make payment


Problem is:

If user clicks Sign-up button then I lead him to Stripe page where he makes payments

Once the payment is completed, Stripe redirects user to a url we choose

Now if after payment user comes back to my app, he will have to fill register form at my app (Firebase Auth). But I have no way to actually know if this user has actually made the payment or not since the payment actually happened at another site (Stripe link)


How do I actually sort this and make payment and sign up option better? I don't want to integrate Stripe Sdk in my app or do any payments inside my app.
My tech stack is:
Flutter web
Firestone for DB
Firebase Auth for registration
I dont have any backend service as such.
All the documents and tutorials I find aren't actually addressing the web part or Stripe links,they are rather focused on Stripe package
Any guidance would be much helpful 

Stripe Payment Links can be configured to include the Checkout Session ID in the success URL the customer will be redirected to after a successful payment.  You can add {CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID} anywhere in the URL and it will be replaced on redirect, like this:
https://example.com/checkout_success?session={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}

When your customer lands on this URL you can do the following:

Grab the Checkout Session ID from the URL
Retrieve the Checkout Session from the Stripe API
Check the payment_status and/or other properties you're interested in
Redirect the customer to your app and include whatever information you see fit to continue the process

This approach does require you to set up a server to handle the initial redirection from the Payment Link.  The flow would be:
App -> Payment Link -> Your Server -> App

And the steps above would happen on the Your Server step.

This is definitely very clean and recommended approach but I didn't want to set any server for the application. Is there any tweak I can do to manage it without the need of creating a server just to handle session

Not really, no.  You need a secure, trusted place to check the status of the Checkout Session (to confirm if you actually got paid or not) and you also need a place your app trusts.
